# distance function on compact Riemannian manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Show that:
Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold, then the distance function $r(x) := \operatorname{dist}(x, p)$ can not be smooth on $M$\{$p$}.

(1)As i know, by Hopf-Rinow theorem, $M$ must be complete, however, i don't know how to describe the smooth of distance function. It is easy to show the function is not smooth near $p$ as one can choose normal coordinates around p.... But how about other point? How to deal with that?

(2)If we consider one special case: simply-connected compact Manifold with non-negative sectional curvature, $r^2$ is smooth because of Cartan-Hardmard theorem, why $r$ can not be smooth?

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21295/smoothness-of-distance-function-in-riemannian-manifolds): "It's never smooth for a compact manifold. Consider a diameter -- the maximum of the function. It's not smooth there. For example, consider $S^n$. You get cone-type singularities. "

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde ，how can this show the function not be smooth everywhere?..

Comment: @ymm "how can this show the function not be smooth everywhere?" ... that's not what he claimed.

Comment: The distance function is smooth away from the point $p$ and the cut-locus of $p$, with a unit gradient vector.

Comment: Hint: Consider the restriction of $r(x)$ to a normal ball centered at $p$ and write this restriction in the normal coordinates.

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan, yes ,this can easy to show $r(x)$ is not smooth near p, but for other points? There the exponential map is not a diffeomorphism.....

Comment: @ymm To show that a function is not everywhere smooth, it suffices to find one point where smoothness fails. As for other points It depends on the metric, on the points and is irrelevant for your question.

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan, maybe i have a wrong expression, the problem wants you to show the function can not be $C^1$ in any point of $M$.

Comment: @ymm: The expression "any" is ambiguous and should be avoided when you are still learning how to write math: In some contexts it means "every" and in other contexts it means "some." What you wrote in your question was very clear, what you are writing in a comment is not. If you are asked to prove that "there is no $x\in M$ such that $r(x)$ is $C^1$-smooth at $x$," then you are being asked to prove a false statement. Most likely, you are misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan，maybe you are right...The origin of this problem was not wrote in English....It has two questions in this subject: (1)the first is what i have shown: prove $r$ is not smooth near $P$, choose the normal coordinate then we can solve it;(2) the most concerns me is the second one: if $M$ is compact then $r(x)$ can not be $C^1$ in $M\{P}$.....I did a simple process to the question according to my understanding.....

Comment: Oh, (2) is a very different question from what you wrote in your post, you have to use compactness to prove it (and you are misinterpreting the Cartan-Hadamard theorem since it cannot be applied to compact manifolds).

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan....I'm sorry, could you give me more details?........